# Getting net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE all of a sudden on APIs

Tags: javascript, cors

After a OSX update I started to get `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` chrome, on any localhost apps that try to go to an external API. They worked fine before. It's some CORS issue but not sure how to fix it. It's happening in all the browsers. Some research says just to reboot which I did, I even rebooted my router. I am out of options.

Comment: Just to make sure, is it on Chrome only?

Comment: No every browser. Firefox gives the error: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at xxx. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS." It's like some global CORS setting went into affect. Worked fine for every till now. Other apps I am working on have the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure that that external API replies with correct data? E.g. perhaps the external API closes connections when it sees `Origin: http://localhost`.

Comment: Yes. I own the external API. It works on my laptop, it just stopped working on my iMac (Yosemite related?).